# transform feedback empty buffer

Tags: opengl, transform, lwjgl, opengl-3, feedback

EDIT: I simply forgot to bind the shader. Now it's working.

I am currently trying to get transform feedback to run but it doesn't. I am using OpenGL 3.3 and followed the steps from [this](https://open.gl/feedback) tutorial converting it to Java and LWJGL.

Shader code:

```
#version 330 core

in float inValue;
out float outValue;

void main(){
    outValue = sqrt(inValue);
}
```

Shader class code:

```
... loading shaders, uniforms, attribute locations etc. ...

public void setTransformFeedbackVaryings(String[] varyings, boolean interleaved){
    int bufferMode = interleaved ? GL_INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS : GL_SEPERATE_ATTRIBS;
    glTransformFeedbackVaryings(programID, varyings, bufferMode);
}

public void compile(){
    glLinkProgram(programID);
    glValidateProgram(programID);
    ... //error catching
}
```

Other:

```
...
//sets the list of feedback varyings names with GL_INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS
shader.setTransformFeedbackVaryings(new String[]{"outValue"}, true);

//linking and validating shader
shader.compile();

attribLocation = shader.getAttribLocation("inValue");

//create VAO
VAO = glGenVertexArrays();
glBindVertexArrayObject(VAO);

//create data buffer
FloatBuffer buffer = ... //contains the values to be send to the shader

//create VBO
VBO = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribLocation);
glVertexAttribPointer(attribLocation, 1, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

//create test buffer
FloatBuffer test = ... //some values

//create transform feedback buffer
TBO = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, test, GL_STATIC_READ);

//perform feedback
glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);

glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, TBO);
glBeginTransformFeedBack(GL_POINTS);

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, NUM_VALUES);

glEndTransformFeedback();

glDisable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);

glFlush();

//read data
FloatBuffer feedback = ... //empty buffer
glGetBufferSubData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, feedback);
```

The values I get from the feedback buffer are those from the test buffer. Hence writing and reading the buffers seems to work. When leaving out the test buffer and loading an empty one to the `TBO` the results are all 0. 
 I tried replacing the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` with `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER` when using the `TBO` as I read [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/663281-transform-feedback-returns-empty-data/) but it didn't work either.

I don't get any OpenGL Errors btw.

Comment: Where is the source code for `shader.setTransformFeedbackVariants()`?

Comment: Another thing: with the current code, your readback operation will simply fail because there is nothing bound to the `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER` target. The `BindBufferBase` does not count for that.

Comment: do you mean I should replace the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` with `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER` when dealing with the `TBO` or anything else?

Comment: Creating the TF buffer as `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` will work in the GL (although it might confuse some performance optimizations of the driver). However, when using `glGetBufferSubData(target,...)`, you need to have the buffer you want to read back bound to `target`. In your current code, it is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, so you should read back that one. However, switching totally to `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER` makes much more sense to me.

Comment: replaced all `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` flags with `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER` where I use the `TBO`. In case you meant that it doesn't work, I just tried...